# Move Object with mouse depending on its rotation Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the script below to move an object (on X and Z axis) smoothly with mouse movement, it works perfectly on the world's axis, I mean when the object's rotation is (0,0,0).

But how can I make the object move on its local axis (I mean when its X rotation is -20, its Z movement should be progressive)?

**Script:**

```
private Vector3 screenPoint;
private Vector3 offset;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

        offset = transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);

        Vector3 curPosition = new Vector3((Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint).x + offset.x), 2, (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint).z + offset.z));

        float newX = Mathf.Clamp(curPosition.x, -3f, 3f);
        float newZ = Mathf.Clamp(curPosition.z, -6f, 1.5f);

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(newX, transform.position.y, newZ), 10 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I found the answer, and it was simple:

- Create an empty gameobject and make it the parent of the moving object.
- Apply the rotations to the parent, so the child has no rotations.
- Attach the code to the child, but use "transform.localposition" instead of "transform.position".